# No LaTeX formulas in comments on the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, user-interface, latex

The LaTeX formulas look fine in the answers on the Android app, but they are not interpreted in the comments.

Is it voluntary, or will it be corrected in the future?

Comment: Just found the Render MathJax button thanks to Shadow Wizard's comment. This solves the problem partially. Thanks !